# Featuretools: skip the target feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, featuretools

When using [Featuretools](https://www.featuretools.com/) is it possible to skip the target feature? For example, consider the iris dataset

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/639388c2cbc2120a14dcf466e85730eb8be498bb/iris.csv')
target = "species"
data[target] = data[target].map({'setosa':0, 'versicolor':1, 'virginica':2})
# Make an entityset and add the entity
es = ft.EntitySet(id='iris dataset')
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='data', dataframe=data,
                         make_index=True, index='index')

# Run deep feature synthesis with transformation primitives
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_entity='data',
                                      trans_primitives=['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'])
```

The generated `feature_matrix`contains useless features such as `sepal_width + species`. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ignore_variables` in DFS to ignore the target feature.

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity='data',
    trans_primitives=['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'],
    ignore_variables={'data': ['species']},
)
```